# assign many values nested in an object from the parent assignment in Object.assign

Tags: javascript, object, computed-properties

I have been experimenting with assigning many values nested in an object from within the parent assignment in Object.assign. I got it to work the way I wanted it. However, I do not know how or why it is working. Why does style need to be computed before the second Object.assign will evaluate it?

```js
var cards = Object.assign(card=document.createElement('div'),style=card.style, {
id:'cards',
innerHTML:'hello world',
  [style]:[Object.assign(style,{
    width:"300px",
    margin:'auto',
    color:'green',
    height:'300px',
  })]
  });
  
var body=  document.querySelector('body');
  body.appendChild(cards);
```

Comment: That's not really working.

Comment: what do you mean? are you on chrome?

Comment: @Bergi I just tried it on both firefox and chrome and it works with both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code does not do what you want, and does not work the way you think it does. Notice that you are [accidentally introducing global variables](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and your computed property key will be the useless and unused `"[object CSSStyleDeclaration]"`. It just does have the desired effect because `Object.assign(style, …)` is evaluted, but doing it in the nested object has no impact.

You should just write

```
var card = document.createElement('div');
Object.assign(card, {
    id:'cards',
    innerHTML:'hello world'
});
var style = card.style;
Object.assign(style, {
    width:"300px",
    margin:'auto',
    color:'green',
    height:'300px',
});

var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(cards); // probably not necessary, cards already is part of the document
```

or possibly even simpler

```
var card = document.createElement('div');
card.id = 'cards';
card.innerHTML = 'hello world';
var style = card.style;
style.width = "300px";
style.margin = 'auto';
style.color = 'green';
style.height = '300px';
```

---

Maybe it helps to see what you were doing wrong when we desugar the `Object.assign`s. Your code is equivalent to

```
_temp1 = card=document.createElement('div'); // global variable!
_temp2 = style=card.style; // global variable!
_temp3 = {
    id:'cards',
    innerHTML:'hello world'
};
_temp4 = style;
_temp5 = {
    width:"300px",
    margin:'auto',
    color:'green',
    height:'300px',
};
for (p in _temp5) // the Object.assign(style, {…})
    _temp4[p] = _temp5[p];

_temp3[String(style)] = [_temp4]; // WTF

for (p in _temp2) // the first part of Object.assign(card, style, …)
    _temp1[p] = _temp2[p]; // WTF
for (p in _temp3) // the second part of Object.assign(card, …, {…})
    _temp1[p] = _temp3[p];

var cards = _temp1;

var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(cards);
```

Comment: I am more interested in the explanation for why it does work. I am not interested in alternative approaches. Also your link  "accidentally introducing global variables" does not work. I would prefer to know how I am accidentally introducing global variables. That is really the heart of the question. If that is really where the mistake is happening.

Comment: @Arrow Oops, accidentally converted it to https while it's only available through http

Comment: I think you are right about the global variable part. However, can you explain how that is happening in the answer? That would make it a much more valuable answer. Also if you can achieve the same type of nesting in your solutions that would be much more meaningful, as it would show to think about the problem. I was already aware of solutions you provided. if you can achieve the same type of nesting it would make the answer far better.

Comment: No, the whole point is that nesting anything does not work. `Object.assign` does not work recursively, and you cannot assign a new object to `card.style` - you need to mutate the existing one.

Comment: I reason I use the comma was so the left side get evaluated first. which is why I do not need to mutate it. The fact that there is global in the arguments provides no insights into why it works. I could have just as easily used a closure and it would work just fine as it is right now. Also if I  followed your logic the second Object.assign wouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: It "works" because you're ultimately still doing `Object.assign(card, …, {…})` and `Object.assign(card.style, {…})`. But alongside that, many other things do happen that you do not want to happen at all. Just do a `console.log(card)` after your assignments, and inspect what properties you created on it.

Comment: Object.assign is not what makes this work. it's because I create another instance of the card and call it style which allows its properties to be merged into cards. if you replace both instances of style with card it will not work. What are those things? please be specific and adjust your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Arrow You're not creating any "instances". But yes, you create that alias `style` for `card.style`, although you really really should not do it in an argument of `Object.assign` (you're just lucky it doesn't have disastrous effects).

Comment: I am selecting your answer because you correctly corrected my improper use of the word instance in javascript.The other information I did not find useful.

Comment: By the way, I can solve your global variable problem by doing this.       
 var cards = Object.assign(cards=document.createElement('div'),cards = cards.style, {
id:'cards',
innerHTML:'hello world',
  [cards]:[Object.assign(cards,{
    width:"300px",
    margin:'auto',
    color:'green',
    height:'300px',
  })]
  });
  
var body=  document.querySelector('body');
  body.appendChild(cards);

Comment: @Arrow No, that still doesn't fix the problems.

Comment: you replaced sugar with splenda, and now I don't want it anymore. I apprecate the update answer :-) 
const div = name => document.createElement(name);
const cards = x => Object.assign(div(x),{id:'cards', innerHTML:'hello world'});
const body = document.querySelector('body'); 
const styles = { width:"300px", margin:'auto', color:'green', height:'300px' };  
const card = cards('div');
for(let p in styles){card.style[p]= styles[p]};
body.appendChild(card);

Comment: Yes, that looks more reasonable.